# Detect tld | http(s) | ftp

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use the following code to detect if a tld and/or http(s)|FTP is being used.

```
function detectTld(text) {
    return text.match('(www.|.com|.net|.org|.me|http|ftp)');
}
```

with the following calling the function:

```
    var detectTld= detectTld($(this).val());
    if (detectTld) {
        $('#uriWarning').removeClass('hidden-xs-up');
    }
```

But it seems to be matching text that is, for example `visit me at home` or the word `become` is getting flagged because of the `com`.

Could somebody please help me with how to fix this in order to get the `.tld` to work, as well as both `http` and `https`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `.` in a regular expression matches any character. Escape it (`\.`) to match a literal period.

Keep in mind that there are a lot more TLDs than you've listed here, though... if you're trying to detect URLs to automatically link them, you may be better off going about this a different way.

Comment: I changed to `(www\.|\.com|\.net|\.org|me|http|ftp)` and still have same results. _(ps: yes, I know about the tld list... just some pseudocode to present my issue)_